# The Load Balancer was unable to find a placement for one or more of the Service's Replicas

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The problem with deployment. Everything is okay in develop cluster, but fails to deploy successfully in on-premises cluster.

Initially I had 3-nodes cluster and got this warning very often, then I added two more nodes and amount of failed replicas has reduced, but not disappeared.

I'm confused with the messages of this warning, can anybody explain what does it mean?

> The Load Balancer was unable to find a placement for one or more of the Service's Replicas:
>   fabric:/Dev.Fabric/CommentsCacheActorService Primary Partition f2b6415c-a69d-4447-a4b0-74cad27e5692 could not be placed, possibly, due to the following constraints and properties:
>   TargetReplicaSetSize: 1
>   Placement Constraint: N/A
>   Depended Service: N/A
>
> Constraint Elimination Sequence:
>   ServiceTypeDisabled/NodesBlockListed eliminated 5 possible node(s) for placement -- 0/5 node(s) remain.
>
> Nodes Eliminated By Constraints
>
> ServiceTypeDisabled/NodesBlockListed  Nodes must not have ServiceType Disabled or be BlockListed due to Node's Pause/Deactivate Status:
>
> FaultDomain:fd:/dc4/r0 NodeName:vm3 NodeType:NodeType0 NodeTypeName:NodeType0 UpgradeDomain:UD3 UpgradeDomain: ud:/UD3 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
>   FaultDomain:fd:/dc3/r0 NodeName:vm2 NodeType:NodeType0 NodeTypeName:NodeType0 UpgradeDomain:UD2 UpgradeDomain: ud:/UD2 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
>   FaultDomain:fd:/dc2/r0 NodeName:vm1 NodeType:NodeType0 NodeTypeName:NodeType0 UpgradeDomain:UD1 UpgradeDomain: ud:/UD1 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
>   FaultDomain:fd:/dc1/r0 NodeName:vm0 NodeType:NodeType0 NodeTypeName:NodeType0 UpgradeDomain:UD0 UpgradeDomain: ud:/UD0 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None
>   FaultDomain:fd:/dc5/r0 NodeName:vm4 NodeType:NodeType0 NodeTypeName:NodeType0 UpgradeDomain:UD4 UpgradeDomain: ud:/UD4 Deactivation Intent/Status: None/None

It is very strange because this warning goes away with time. Probably it is because of rebalancing. Any ideas about what constraint is mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You are right about rebalancing part. Here is an excerpt from [Cluster Resource Manager Management Integration](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-management-integration.md) article.

> In each of these conditions you’ll see a health report from the
>   Cluster Resource Manager that provides information to help you
>   determine what is going on and why the service can’t be placed. We
>   call this process the “Constraint Elimination Sequence”. During it,
>   the system walks through the configured constraints affecting the
>   service and records what they eliminate. This way when services aren’t
>   able to be placed, you can see which nodes were eliminated and why.

It comes down to your constraint types and priorities.

How do you resolve it? Well, this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b3b6aba-d2ec-46fe-82ad-62670787dde3/errors-deploying-multiple-applications?forum=AzureServiceFabric) might help. It talks about making changes in Windows registry to address heap size. Since I don't have this issue at the moment, I am not inclined to apply changes. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looks like there is all information I need to resolve this issue. Hack with changing registry looks very dirty and I would not use it on prod or even staging, so I will not try it.

Comment: Great. If you resolve it, do you mind updating your question with a solution, and/or marking it answered.